# Convert a query of views into a single query with derived tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-view

Is it possible to convert (as in get the query as text) a query that consists of a lot of views within views into a query that is just based on the original tables?

The obvious is to go through all the views and then do it manually but wondered whether or not there was a quicker way?

Comment: Could you please specify which RDBMS you are using? (MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.)

Comment: I do not think that there is a general solution to this problem if that is what you're asking, at least not one that is practical.

Comment: Ok, I was afraid of that, couldn't find the question answered (positive or negative) anywhere and wanted to be certain.

Comment: Not sure I follow what you are asking, do you want to query some view definitions and the create a join of several of the view definitions?

Answer (score 1):

It's not pretty, and like @David Faber commented, not sure how practical this will be, but here goes...

There's a whole lot of assumptions that one has to make for this to work, like

- All of the views start with SELECT. (no CTE's)
- The view is not enclosed in [ ] when referenced in another view
- View names don't have spaces in them
- This version only goes 1 level deep, but it should be possible to resolve any additional views you find in the output in a similar fashion.
- And probably some more I didn't think of

I'm using the sys tables, and not the newer schema information objects, simply because I know the sys table structure better.

Assuming the following view

```
CREATE VIEW VW_DUMMY
AS
SELECT c.Name as Company, g.Name as [Group], gu.UserId
FROM VW_Company c
    JOIN VW_Group g ON c.Id = g.CompanyId
    JOIN VW_GroupUser gu ON g.Id = gu.GroupId AND gu.CompanyId = c.Id
```

Here's what I did.

1) Grab the view definition from syscomments for VW_DUMMY.

2) Strip off the CREATE VIEW part

2) Grab a list of objects that VW_DUMMY depends on from sysdepends

3) Grab the view definition from syscomments for all the dependant objects.

4) Strip off the CREATE VIEW part

5) Replace the name of the 'depends' object in the original view with the
 definition...

1)

```
DECLARE @SQL    VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @SQL = REPLACE((
    SELECT c.text AS [text()]
    FROM syscomments c 
    WHERE c.id = OBJECT_ID('VW_DUMMY')
    FOR XML PATH('')), '&#x0D;', '');
```

2)

```
SET @SQL = SUBSTRING(@SQL, PATINDEX('%SELECT%', @SQL), LEN(@SQL))
```

3), 4) and 5)

```
SELECT @SQL = REPLACE(@SQL, ' ' + name + ' ', '(' + SUBSTRING(text, PATINDEX('%SELECT%', text), LEN(text)) + ') ')
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME(depid) as name,
    REPLACE((
        SELECT c.text AS [text()]
        FROM syscomments c 
        WHERE c.id = d.depid
        FOR XML PATH('')), '&#x0D;', '') as text
    FROM sysdepends d
WHERE d.id = OBJECT_ID('VW_DUMMY')
AND exists(select 1 from sysobjects c where c.id = d.depid and c.type='V')) data

SELECT @SQL
```

I tried in on VW_DUMMY in my database, and the output is some of the worst formatted code that you might ever see, but the result is the same as the view.

Here's the output (bad formatting is deliberate)

```
SELECT c.Name as Company, g.Name as [Group], gu.UserId
FROM(SELECT *
FROM Company


) c
    JOIN(SELECT *
FROM [Group]



) g ON c.Id = g.CompanyId
    JOIN(SELECT *
FROM [GroupUser]



) gu ON g.Id = gu.GroupId AND gu.CompanyId = c.Id
```

Does that help?